# how to set dynamic variable and pass it to JSF like spring mvc?

Tags: java, jsf, spring-mvc

In spring, I can do like this

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.putAll(runtimeService.getVariables(executionId));
return new ModelAndView("page1", model);
```

runtimeService.getVariables(executionId) is returning a map
For example,

```
String Object
"id"   "123"
"value" "4"
```

Then i can directly use ${id} to access the value

Variable name "id" is dynamic,

I am not sure how to do it in JSF way, since it uses getters and setters.

This should be simple, i am new to JSF :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `Map` in your `Managed Bean` and render it on XHTML using `#`

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PersonBean{
  private Map<String, String> personPropertyMap;
  //setter + getters
}
```

on page

```
#{personBean.personPropertyMap['property1']}
```

Comment: um..this is acceptable. But i would like to type #{property1} instead of #{personBean.personPropertyMap['property1']}, i would accept this solution if there isn't any better one.

Comment: then you can set it directly in request/session or other scope which EL will resolve in pure JSP style.. this isn't prefrable since it would be bit hard to manage

Comment: @Tommy: you can also use `#{personBean.personPropertyMap.property1}` if the key doesn't need to be dynamic.